# Issue with VBA cell value and if

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display dollars on the range D15:D54 when B6 = San Francisco, otherwise euros. But my VBA does not work. Anyone can help, please?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Auto(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("B6").Value = "San Francisco" Then
Range("D15:D54").Value = "Dollars ($)"
Else
Columns("D15:D54").Value = "Euros (€)"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Columns` to `Range` - also, `Worksheet_Auto` is not a handler for any event.

Answer (score 2):

### A Worksheet Change: Source Cell vs Destination Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Check if source cell is not among the changed cells.
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B6")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Prevent re-triggering this event when writing to the destination range.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Prevent events staying disabled if an error occurs.
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    ' Use the 'IIf' function to save a few lines.
    ' Use 'StrComp' with 'vbTextCompare' to ignore case ('SAN = san').
    ' Use 'CStr' to prevent failure if the source contains an error value.
    Range("D15:D54").Value = IIf( _
        StrComp(CStr(Range("B6").Value), "San Francisco", vbTextCompare) = 0, _
        "Dollars ($)", _
        "Euros (€)")

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```